# Java: Invoke a method from a class declared as a feild

Tags: java, reflection

I've currently got functioning code, but an update to a mod I'm interacting with is causing issues.

Here is a mock-up of the other mods code I'm accessing.

IHandler.class

```
public abstract interface IHandler
{
  public abstract int addValue(int value);
}
```

Old: Item.class

```
public final class Item
{
  public static IHandler handler;

  public static int addValue(int value)
  {
    handler.addValue(value);
  }
}
```

They used Item.addValue(value); in their code

Mock-up of the Code I'm currently using (works with old code above)

```
Class<?> itemclass = Class.forName("Item");
Method addValue = itemclass.getDeclaredMethod("addValue", Integer.TYPE);
addValue.invoke(item.newInstance(), 25);
```

The issue I'm having is Item.class has changed.

New: Item.class

```
public final class Item
{
  public static IHandler handler;
}
```

They now use Item.handler.addValue(value); in their code

With the handy wrapper removed I can't seem to access the method anymore.
I'm not sure how to get the instance of the handler so I can invoke the method again.
Here is where I got to before admitting defeat :)

```
Class<?> itemclass = Class.forName("Item");
Field handler = itemclass.getDeclaredField("handler");
Class<?> iHandler = handler.getType();
Method addValue = iHandler.getMethod("addValue", Integer.TYPE);
addValue.invoke(item.newInstance(), 25);
```

I'm sure its something simple I'm overlooking.

EDIT:
Knew it was something simple I was overlooking :)
addValue.invoke(handler.getValue(null), 25);

Thankyou millimoose

Comment: [`addValue.invoke(handler.getValue(null), 25)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Comment: (Making an instance of `Item` when `handler` is `static` doesn't make a lot of sense, and `IHandler.addValue()` has to be called on an instance of `IHandler`, not of `Item`.)

Comment: That said, personally, I'd consider doing any heavy reflection like this using [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) – Java ships with an implementation of Javascript that can interoperate with Java objects.

Comment: Use addValue.invoke(null, 25); for static calls.

Comment: lol I started trying anything item.newInstance() is just where I stopped ;)
-----
I was coming back to post I found a solution:
addValue.invoke(handler.getValue(iHandler), 25)
-----
Your, addValue.invoke(handler.getValue(null), 25); is better though ;)

Comment: @Tyco You got it the other way around. The method was `static` before, and the object parameter to `invoke()` is **ignored** in that case. Changing it to `null` doesn't change anything, although it's arguably a little better since it's somewhat clearer that it's a static method to someone reading the code. However, `addValue` is now an instance method of `IHandler`, so the problem is the opposite: getting the correct instance to pass to `invoke()`.